# Placement of three figures in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning

I want to position 3 figures in beamer, with the first two justified at the left, the second being below the first, and the third at the right. However, I need the third image to be vertically centered, and not below the first two.

In the following code, I would like the image3 to be at the right of images 1 and 2

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My title}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \frame{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{image1.png}}\\
        \frame{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{image2.png}}
    \end{flushleft}
    \frame{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{image3.png}} 
\end{frame}
```

However, with this the third image is below the second. I would like it to be vertically centered on the frame, justified at the right.

Comment: Please post a single frame and three images code.

Comment: like I said, I don't have any code that is working

Comment: Or maybe a layout of what you want

Comment: It doesn't have to work. We only need something to understand how you try to do it.

Comment: @percusse I added what I tried

Comment: Great. Thank you. I'll make a MWE now. In the meantime would you care to look at our description of what we babble all the time about [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Welcome to the site by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For aligning the different parts of the `frame` environment, `beamer` offers the `columns` environment. Here you can stack two images in one and the other in another column in a pretty straightforward fashion.

The other kind of placement options can be included as if you are operating in a regular frame inside a column.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe} % <-- for dummy images
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{image frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            %\centering %Uncomment this line for horizontal centering 
            \includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{example-image-a}%

            \includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{example-image-b}%
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-c}%
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]